# Storing user details in claims - searching through users

Tags: wif, claims-based-identity

I'm building a set of custom claims, each of which defines information about a user, such as Age, Gender, Address, etc. Claims are then stored in the database as key/value pair. Claim types can be added dynamically so that user information can be expanded if required.

However, I've encountered a slight limitation which is requirement that claim values are strings. In particular, this is rather visible in situations where there is large number of users ( > 100.000) and I would like to perform a complex search query where i.e. I'm looking for all users with age > 50. Assuming that BirthDate is another claim stored as string in the database, there is definitely a loss on the SQL performance between two scenarios of issuing query directly against column of datetime type, or searching through claim sets for all users.

How to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

How do you store claims in your database is up to you. You are not forced to use strings. You can use whatever type you want. That is separate from the fact that WIF might store its value as strings.

Comment: That is clear, however, I'm trying to create a generic UI where you could define claim types and then add each claim type to specific identity. I'd also like to build generalized service which would generate a token by using those claim types. I can't do that if I'm storing age in i.e. UserProfiles table - that is then specific logic. I'm thinking about extending my ClaimTypes table to introduce ValueType property and then for each specific claim I might have 3 columns in the database, IntValue, DateTimeValue and StringValue. That would allow me to issue faster queries.